# Trouble with "dictionary" creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

OK, first-off let me tell you that I'm *too* far from being considered experienced in JavaScript... (<del>perhaps I'm even trying to implement something not actually supported by the language?</del>).

So... here we are...

**I want to create a structure like this** (it's just an illustrative example) :

```
Addresses
    --- John
           --- Phone
           --- Address
    --- Peter
           --- Phone
           --- Address
```

So, I've seen (or perhaps I'm just guessing) that I can do something like that (I've run all my tests in Chrome's JavaScript console) :

```
var addresses = [];
addresses["John"] = {};
addresses["John"].Phone = "12312312312";
// And so on...
```

**However :**

- If I do `addresses['123'] = {};` then a proper 124-entry array is constructed.
- If I do `addresses['somestring'] = {};` then `addresses` remains an empty array `[]`.

---

What am I doing wrong? Is there no native support for proper dictionaries (or map - no matter how this thing is called) in JavaScript?

---

**Please note:** I want to be able to progressively add entries to addresses, as well as keys to each address entry (and not just create it in one-shot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating an array, but then you are using it as an object instead (which is possible because an array happens to be an object). To contain properties rather than numbered indices, you should use an object:

```
var addresses = {};
addresses["Holmes"] = { Phone: "14", Address: "Baker street 221b" };
```

Comment: Silly me. That *does* make sense, for sure. Thanks a lot, mate! (This JavaScript part is just a tiny fraction of a much much bigger non-JS, non-Web project of mine, and you've just saved me lots of time of trouble with something I'm really not used to be working with...) Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has Objects and Arrays.

Arrays are a type of Object that treats properties with numerical with special significance. It will have a `length` property based on the highest value property name (that is a number), and it has methods such as `push`, `pop` and `forEach` to manipulate its numerical members based on their number.

> If I do `addresses['123'] = {};` then a proper 124-entry array is constructed.

You already have an array. That just adds a member called `123` to it and updates its `length`.

> `If I do addresses['somestring'] = {};`

This will add that member to the array, but it won't appear in any of the regular means of accessing array members. You have to access it by name.

Don't give named properties to arrays. Use a plain object.

> Is there no native support for proper dictionaries

An object is as close as you can get.

If you want something ordered use an array with numerical properties.

If you want something with named keys, use an object.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this `addresses['somestring'] = {};` you wil get an empty array because `{}` you are assigning an empty object.

Rather if you do `addresses["dd"] = {s: "s"}` the `addresses` will have the object

Comment: When you are using a non-numeric index with an array, it's a property instead of an item in the array, so the array is empty because you haven't put anything in it. Even an empty object counts as an item if you put it in an array, e.g. `addresses[0] = {};` would make the length 1.

Comment: thnq for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does *not* have dictionaries or maps or associative arrays.

It does, however, have objects which can be quite similar.  (They can also be quite different, so that is essential to know.)

To make things more confusing, an array *is* an object.  You can put random properties on an array and it will work -- like an object.

Javascript arrays take integer[*] indexes and adjust the `.length` property.

Objects take string property names.  This is important: If you use something that *is not* a string, it will be converted into one .. usually called `[Object object]`

Might want to read this:
http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

[*] Yea, yea, yea -- they are really strings behind the scenes.  It is easier to think of them as integers and avoid that grief.